# App is not indexable by Google Search в Манифесте

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Погуглив нашел решение на ошибку в манифесте:

> App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one
>   Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent-filler. See issue explanation for
>   more details.

Нужно добавить ссылку на сайт:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
```

Но непонятно одно что означает префикс?

```
android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
```

Answer (score 4):

если нет особого желания или потребности морочиться с deeplink можно добавить в манифест строчку

```
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
```

Answer (score 3):

Это значит что будут отфильтрованы не все ссылки на *www.example.com*, а только те у которых путь начинается с "/gizmos":

*http://www.example.com**/gismos**/bla/bla.html*

Comment: А без него можно, без префикса?

Answer (score -2):

Я нашёл это решение в англоязычном stackoverflow - там в шапке написано GizmosActivity - подозреваю, что это имя разработчика, и всё.

Comment: Ваш ответ не является ответом на вопрос или решением проблемы, но я думаю, что он бы неплохо подошел в качестве комментария